# Making GWT ui better?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I have an application developed using **GWT and GXT**. Most of my screens are like search or detail kind of pages.

Now i am adding some more functionalities with that. In that i require some nice representation with **images, arrows, links, models**. I finding its very complex to do it in GXT.

Is there any other **libraries or frameworks** to do this?

That supposed to be easily integrated with **GWT/GXT** without much effort.

Please help me out on this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason why you do not want to venture the CSS route and are looking for libraries? I mean, if you are good with CSS then you can start with plain GWT stripped-off of all its defualt CSS and incorporate your design ground up. That is the perhaps the best (only?) way to design your web-app once you have your Photoshop mock-up ready.

You may ofcourse depend on libraries, which come with their own CSS, but your web-application will look no different from the next app designed with the same library.

Comment: yes. you are right. but here i m not telling only about css. We already have our own css for the application. But What i wanted to do exactly is I wanted to represent some complex detail as diagram(something like flow diagrams, process diagrams, links etc ). AS i feel it is not easy to done in GWT itself. Correct me if i am wrong. Thank you for your reply

Comment: You might want to check out http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/. It's a nice js library that can do free flow diagrams. Can be an overkill if your requirements are simple. You need to write your own GWT wrappers (JavaScriptObject) to use it in your GWT application